# CKEditor Widget editable make a div work like an input

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

For some reason CKEditor doesn't allow inputs in widgets by default. There is mention that you can add it to `dtd.$editables` but a quick test showed it wasn't editable for me so I am trying to use the recommended `divs`.

The problem is I want placeholders, adding a placeholder to a div in a modern browser with pure css isn't a problem. The problem, as with the main editor, is that CKEditor despises empty editables - it adds a `<br>` on a completely empty editable which stops the placeholder showing. When editing and then removing content it adds the unicode character for nothingness - `&#8203;`.

Question: How can I make CKEditor treat an empty editable as.. empty, and not insert a random `<br>` or `&#8203;`?

```
editables: {
    // This one is rich, allowing italic and bold
    caption: {
        selector: '.image-caption',
        allowedContent: 'strong em',
        //disallowedContent: 'br' // Doesnt work
    },
    // And this one is pretending to be a plaintext input
    alt: {
        selector: '.image-alt',
        allowedContent: true
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to this? i have the exact same problem..